# Do I have to use a disconnected approach when only inserting in a database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

We need to create a small website with a database (accdb) in ASP.NET. This database will only have records added while it's in operation (gathering survey data). Our teacher prefers to use DataSets (disconnected approach) for any database, but this is overkill for such a small website. This is why I was wondering, is there any reason not to use a connected approach (DataReader)? Can any concurrency errors occur when only inserting?

In other words: connected or disconnected approach when you only insert into the database?

Comment: When you keep the connection open for  minimum time period, you will able provides max security for db. It will also help
you to have impact on overall performance.

Comment: As well, a `DataSet` technically uses a `DataReader` under the hood to read the data. The disconnected aspect is only that the `DataSet` is now an in memory representation of that data returned instead of you writing that code to read from the `DataReader` yourself.

Comment: Offline DataSets carry more risks of concurrency conflicts than direct inserts. But apart from that both can have them or can be made concurrent safe.

Comment: @Tejs I don't even know why I'm mentioning DataReaders, you don't use them when inserting.. (or do you?)

Comment: Correct. That's a complete misnomer for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technical answer is "No", since a disconnected approach has no meaning for an insert operation.